# How can we have more than 3 file attachments per note?

Tags: attachments

How can we have more than 3 file attachments per note?

CiviCRM 4.7.1

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Administer/System Settings/Misc...you should see an option for the maximum number of attachments?